# Python Pandas: Filter Dataframe by applying regular expression

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I am able to filter a dataframe based on the elements of a list like this;

```
import pandas as pd
W1 = ['Animal','Ball','Cat','Derry','Element','Lapse','Animate this']
W2 = ['Krota','Catch','Yankee','Global','Zeb','Rat','Try']
df = pd.DataFrame({'W1':W1,'W2':W2})

l1 = ['Animal','Zeb','Q']
print df[df['W1'].isin(l1) | df['W2'].isin(l1)]

        W1     W2
  0   Animal  Krota
  4  Element    Zeb
```

But is there a way to filter by applying regular expressions;
     For ex;

```
 l1 = ['An','Cat']

 Intended result;
          W1         W2
  0   Animal        Krota
  1   Ball          Catch  
  2   Cat           Yankee
  6   Animate this  Try
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
df[df['W1'].str.contains("|".join(l1)) | df['W2'].str.contains("|".join(l1))]


             W1      W2
0        Animal   Krota
1          Ball   Catch
2           Cat  Yankee
6  Animate this     Try
```

Comment: How would you modify this, if `l1= pd.DataFrame({'W1': ['An', 'Ze'] 'W2': ['Kr', 'El']})`? Here `An, Ze`, Kr, El` are `regex` values. Can the entries in a  Dataframe be regex values?

Comment: I am aware, I can use `isin`, if `l1` is a dataframe and I want perfect matches.. but I have a case where the entries in the dataframe `l1` are not going to be perfect matches.. so I probably need to use `regex` values..